# navigationBar.barTintColor always black and not possible to change it

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

The `navigationBar.barTintColor` in my app is always black, and there is no way I can change it. I checked all classes and I never set it to black, but I do set it to `UIColor clearColor`. Still, the bar is black. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I found out that the problem is with my `[UIColor clearColor]`, when I change it to any other color it changes the color like it should, but clearColor makes it appear black.

Answer (score 1):

If its IOS7 try the code below

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor: [<Specify the UIColor you want>];
```

In IOS6 try this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [<Specify the UIColor you want>];
```

Edit:

I think you have given

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This will give black color. If you want any specific tint color, it  must be specifed after clearing

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor <specify your color>];
```

Comment: try this self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yourcolor]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look there

[image]

Try modifying the `Style` and `Translucent` attributes on the navigation bar (top right in image).

If you are having problems modifying the status bar color, try adding this to your .plist (line below).

[image]

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Finally, here's some code you may want.

```
// Status bar color
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:yourStyle];

// Navigation bars color
[UINavigationBar appearance].barStyle = yourStyle;
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor yourColor];

// Navigation bars items color
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

Comment: It isn't working.. do you think it could be that the bar turns black because i have 2 views on top of each other?

Comment: "i have 2 views on top of each other " .You have custom navigation bar ??

Comment: I have a navigationController for my whole app

Comment: Is the navigation bar black in the storyboard (just like the image i posted)? If so, I'm pretty sure turning on the `Translucent` attribute in the attribute inspector will do the trick. Or could the  `Tint color` (in the attributes inspector) be black?

Comment: In my storyboard it is clearColor.
No, checked it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{
       UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0f]
       }];


    CGFloat verticalOffset = -4;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Uncomment to change the color of back button
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // Uncomment to assign a custom backgroung image
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Uncomment to change the back indicator image

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

    // Uncomment to change the font style of the title

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    CGFloat verticalOffset = -4;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: Well, it does change the color of the Navigationbar to white, but I want it to be ` [UIColor clearColor] `, which isn't working with your code too.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha:0];

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: check it second comment.,

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 try:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```